# Strava API - get photos from an activity

Tags: javascript, api, photo, strava, strava-api-v3

I am trying to get Photos from Strava with [https://www.strava.com/api/v3/activities/${activityId}/photos?access_token=${res.access_token}`](https://www.strava.com/api/v3/activities/$%7BactivityId%7D/photos?access_token=$%7Bres.access_token%7D%60), but there are only thumbnail of these photos.
Is there a way to get the full resolution photos somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Get Activity By Id](https://developers.strava.com/docs/reference/#api-Activities-getActivityById) endpoint you get back a [DetailedActivity](https://developers.strava.com/docs/reference/#api-models-DetailedActivity)

This includes a [PhotosSummary](https://developers.strava.com/docs/reference/#api-models-PhotosSummary) object which contains the photos that are currently available through the Stava API v3.

Comment: I am getting `PhotosSummary` objects, but they have "preview" urls, which if visited seem to do nothing but load a grey arrow:

```
#<GrabPolylines:0x084>:0> photo = _.first
=> {"unique_id"=>"bfb94",
 "athlete_id"=>3808,
 "activity_id"=>917,
[...]
 "created_at_local"=>2023-06-03 11:47:29 UTC,
 "urls"=>{"1800"=>"https://d3nn82uaxijpm6.cloudfront.net/assets/media/placeholder-photo@4x-13b0b44cfa828acc8b95d8dc4b8157d87666aa1ea8ef814c6ec36cd542d2b756.png"},
 "sizes"=>{"1800"=>[1372, 1000]}}
```

Comment: Interesting, I'm able to get photos.  Do you think it might be a permission setting on your activities? Ill take a look aver the weekend and get back to you.

Comment: I looked through my Strava Privacy settings, and found the settings that would be at root, and they all seemed to be configured correctly. 

Hm.